# Xslt Headers show only once

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello all i have a question , i am very new to XSLT so this may be a noob question
This is my xml structure

```
<FAQ>
    <!--About Us-->
    <Query Section="About Us">
        <Question>How do I contact Support?</Question>
        <Answer>
          You can connect with us on Twitter or Facebook.
        </Answer>
    </Query>
    <Query Section="About Us">
        <Question>Who we are?</Question>
        <Answer>Will discus it later</Answer>
    </Query>
    <Query Section="Another section">
        <Question>any question?</Question>
        <Answer>answer</Answer>
    </Query>
</FAQ>
```

and this is my XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
    </head>
            <body>
                <h2>FAQS</h2>
                <div border="1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="//*[@Section]">
                        <xsl:sort select="@Section"/>
                        <ul>
                            <li style="color:blue;cursor:pointer" class="Question">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Question"/>
                            </li>
                            <li style="display:none" class="answer">
                                <xsl:value-of select="Answer"/>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting every thing as expected but my headers are getting repeated as
i am getting something like this

- About us
- How do i contact Support
- Answer
- About us
- Who we are?
- Answer
- Another section
- Question
- Answer

but i want some thing like this

- About us
- How do i contact Support
- Answer
- Who we are?
- Answer
- Another section
- Question
- Answer

notice that about us heading is coming only once :) hope  i have explained all things well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This i a grouping issue. The solution is muenchian grouping ([e.g look to this](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)).

Therefor add a key to your xslt:

```
<xsl:key name="kQuerySection" match="Query"  use="@Section"/>
```

And have to loops.

Loop over groups:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Query[
             generate-id() = generate-id(key('kQuerySection', @Section)[1])
              ]">
```

Loop over group members.

```
  <xsl:for-each select="key('kQuerySection', @Section)">
```

Therefore try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="kQuerySection" match="Query"  use="@Section"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>FAQS</h2>
                <div border="1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Query[
                                  generate-id() = generate-id(key('kQuerySection', @Section)[1])
                                  ]">
                        <xsl:sort select="@Section"/>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@Section"/>
                                <xsl:for-each select="key('kQuerySection', @Section)">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li style="color:blue;cursor:pointer" class="Question">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="Question"/>
                                        </li>
                                        <li style="display:none" class="answer">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="Answer"/>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </xsl:for-each>

                            </li>

                        </ul>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir i have done this by another way but your solution is also working fine so vote up for you